# java.lang.NegativeArraySizeException When Making Document Topics Matrix using RMallet

Tags: java, r, lda, rjava, mallet

I'm trying to write some code to get a Mallet Instance List file into a document topics matrix in R. To do this, I read the instance list file into a topic trainer variable called 'topic.model'. Below is the function call I am making to create a document topics matrix in R:

```
theta <- mallet::mallet.doc.topics(topic.model, smoothed = TRUE, normalized = TRUE)
```

I got this working on a smaller instance list file (< 1gb), but for a larger instance list (~15gb) I receive the following error:

> Error in .jcall(wrapper, "[D", "flat_double") :
>     java.lang.NegativeArraySizeException
>   Calls: myfunc ... .jevalArray -> newArray -> structure -> .jcall -> .jcheck
>   Execution halted

I suspect that the somewhere there is an integer overflow, in which `INT_MAX` is exceeded, and the `NegativeArraySizeException` occurs. Interestingly, using the command line, `Mallet` was able to make the document topics file using the `--output-doc-topics` parameter (>150gb). Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.